# get base url in action controller to generate mail body in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am creating a mail body for activating an account, In a controller action I want to get root url to generate a link for activation.I have used `$this->getFrontController()->getBaseUrl()` this is giving '/public' not the complete url.Plz help.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use url view helper to generate urls, if you want. If not you can get full baseUrl in an action as follows:

```
  $fullBaseUrl = $this->view->serverUrl() . $this->view->baseUrl();
  var_dump($fullBaseUrl);
```